# Does operator overloading allows the access to private member without friend?

Tags: c++

Below code, shows a simple operator overloading for `+` to a class Person. according to object encasulation, I should get an error when I access  `p.id` in operator overloading. Why I am not getting it ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


namespace friendDemo {
    class Person {
    private:
        int id;
    public:
        int operator+(const Person& p);
        Person(int id);
    };

    int Person::operator+(const Person& p) {
        // accessing the private member
        cout << p.id << endl;
        return p.id + id;
    }

    Person::Person(int id) : id(id) {
        cout << "Created" << endl;
    }

    void test() {
        Person p1 {1};
        Person p2 {2};
        cout << "p1 + p2 = " << (p1 + p2) << endl;
    }
};



int main() {

    friendDemo::test();

    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
Created
Created
p1 + p2 = 2
3
```

Am I doing proper operator overloading? according to text, I should use friend function to access a private member, but his code is wired(without friend its accessing the private member)

Comment: `operator+` in your example is a member function so it can access all the private fields just fine. If you overload some operator as a free function it would be required to be a friend to access non-public fields.

Comment: If you made a free standing function `int operator+(const Person& lhs, const Person& rhs)`, then that non-member function would have to be a friend in order to access the non-public fields (as per VTT's comment).

Comment: The detail you miss is that your operators are member functions. And then there's the duplicate with its C++ answers

Comment: @aschepler: I know that each member has the full access to the class members.